# Big data generated PHP script

Tags: php, storage

I am working on a small `PHP` script, this script is currently generating over 8gb of pictures daily so I am looking for a solution to prevent problems in the future.

My question is should I keep using the `VPS` to store those pictures ? or instead use a cloud storage service to store them and display them ? Which is the best cloud storage service for my case ? When loading those picture does the load in the server increases ?

Comment: Are the high res images or just tons of images? If high res you could try re-creating them at a smaller size. Server questions are off topic for SO, you might want to try server fault, http://serverfault.com/.

Comment: @chris85 Tons of images

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on some variability in your project.
If you can Maintenance VPS yourself, I think its better to use it because you can use some compression  method in your vps to reduce picture size.
on other hand, using cloud storage helps you to increase storage simply!

Answer (score 0):

The best practice in that kind of job is always comparing cost between hardware and processing time. Now days storage hardwares are cheaper than processing times using CPU and Ram. Why don't you save all image files on every requests and serve your users without processing image creation like how NoSQL serves users?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use AWS(amazon web services) to upload picture, i had the same problem and AWS solution is working fine.you just have to store the url of picture in database and when the picture will load it will not increase the load on your server.

Here is documentation - [AWS documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/)